# How does Logstash process events from a http pooler -> json -> split?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

So I have an OOM problem on a small JSON input, using http_pooler. When debugging this I am missing a crucial piece of information, mainly how does Logstash process the pipeline.

Pipeline config:

- input: http_poller to a http resource that returns a json (10MB)
- filter: json, split that json (into about 2000 objects), some mutations on each field in every object
- output: elasticsearch

The main question here is, does Logstash load into memory the input, process it by splitting it based on the json field I selected, and then on every splitted "row" it will execute the output, or does it need to process the whole filter, and then push it out to output?

I have been looking up info about "periodic_flush", but it seems that it's not doing what I thought it might be doing.

Comment: So, further research leads me to believe that Logstash, while using the split filter, will clone the initial event for every split, thus I might be looking at 2000 times 10MB in memory...

Answer (score 0):

The input will read the entire JSON and process it as a single event.

In older versions of split, if the split target was the same as the source then the entire object was cloned, rather than removing the huge field, iterating over it, and cloning the much smaller objects that do not contain the huge field. It is a massively different in terms of heap usage.

This [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-split/issues/39) has been fixed. The PR was merged into the master thread in January, 2020. When was your logstash version released?

Comment: 18 Aug 2020, 6.8.12, I should be running a version post that PR. Oh, and I did learn a lot from your posts on elastic.co already! :)